# The Grothendieck plus construction for stacks of n-types

Tags: higher-category-theory, stacks, reference-request, ct.category-theory

In Jacob Lurie's Higher Topos Theory, Section 6.5.3, he briefly mentions that to stackify a presheaf of $n$-groupoids, one needs to apply the "+"-construction $\left(n+2\right)$ times, and in general, for a presheaf of $\infty$-groupoids, one needs to apply a transfinite iteration. However, not much detail is given about this. Does anyone know where I can read more about this? Thanks.

Comment: For n=2 it can be found in Igor Bakovic's thesis. For n=1 this was known to Grothendieck and his crew. I would perhaps add to the question the clarifying remark that this +-construction is not Quillen's, but Grothendieck's.

Comment: The Quillen +-construction is fairly well-known; what's the Grothendieck one?

Comment: See Mac Lane--Moerdijk, _Sheaves in Geometry and Logic_, section III.5.

Comment: Thanks for the comments thus far. I should mention I am most interested in finding a reference where  this is done in full generality, not just at the cases $n=1$ or $n=2$, as I need to apply this in an $\infty$-setting. (Although, of course, looking at these special cases will be illuminating)

Comment: I should also mention that is in fact important for me to break this up into substeps- I'm not interested in just a way of computing the stackification, but I am interested in understanding all the different levels in between being a presheaf and stack.

Comment: @David Roberts: Do you know where in his thesis this is discussed? I'm having trouble  finding it in there. Thanks!

Comment: I discussed the +-construction in the context of higher topos theory a little bit, in some notes I wrote: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~rezk/homotopy-topos-sketch.pdf .  See especially sections 3 and 11.

Comment: I think Ross Street discusses in his work on 2-sites the + construction for n=2 with result that plus cube is stackification over (2,2)-sites.

Comment: Street's version is for n=1.  His first paper "Two-dimensional sheaf theory" does it for a strict notion of "2-sheaf", with a fair amount of detail.  His second paper "Characterization of bicategories of stacks" does it for the usual weak notion of stack, but omits any details of how the triple-plus yields a stack.

Answer (score 3):

Thomas Nikolaus and Christoph Schweigert discuss the +-construction for $n=2$ in their paper [Equivariance in Higher Geometry](http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.4558). They split it up into two steps (I think): first producing a pre-2-stack out of a presheaf of 2-groupoids, and then making it a 2-stack.

Applied to the pre-2-stack obtained by delooping the monoidal stack of principal $U(1)$-bundles, one gets exactly the definition of a *bundle gerbe*.

Comment: I don't see any discussion in this paper of the first step, producing a 2-prestack from a 2-presheaf.  They describe the +-construction but the only theorem I see about it is that it takes 2-prestacks to 2-stacks.

Comment: @Mike: you're right. But I think that this first step is rather easy: the Hom-categories are presheaves of categories and can be stackified in the usual (1-categorical) way.

Comment: But that's not quite the same as applying the +-construction $n+2$ times to an $n$-presheaf.

Answer (score 3):

This is discussed in section 3.4.3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.00731 by Mathieu Anel and Chaitanya Leena Subramaniam.

Comment: Inspired by this paper, I wrote up a very similar argument on the [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/plus+construction+on+presheaves).